# How to call one value from stored procedure using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to call one value from a database stored procedure. The procedure IBAccountList) is:

```
SELECT ac.CUAccountID, ac.AccountNumber, ac.BalanceDate, p.Description, ac.ParentAccountID, p.ProductTypeID,
CASE p.ProductTypeID WHEN 1 THEN 
    dbo._Balance(ac.DRAmount, ac.CRAmount) * -1 
ELSE 
    dbo._Balance(ac.DRAmount, ac.CRAmount) 
END AS Balance, 
CASE p.ProductTypeID WHEN 1 THEN 
    NULL 
ELSE (
    SELECT dbo._Balance(intr.DRAmount, intr.CRAmount) 
    FROM CUAccount intr
    WHERE intr.ParentAccountID = ac.CUAccountID
) 
END AS Interest  
FROM CUAccount ac
INNER JOIN CUProduct p ON ac.ProductID = p.ProductID 
WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND
ac.Active = 1 AND
ac.ParentAccountID IS NULL 
ORDER BY ac.AccountNumber
```

I wish to get ProductTypeID from this stored procedure. How would i reference this in ruby. I'm currently trying the following:

```
def fetch_account_type(number)
  @accounttype = @db.call('IBAccountList', @id).map do |accounttype|
  {accounttype: accounttype['ProductTypeID']}
  end
end
```

Comment: How is the performance on this? I see a scalar function all over the place. Scalar functions are notoriously poor performers. I am afraid I am no help with your actual question though. I am a sql guy and have no knowledge of ruby.

Comment: @Sean Lange I dont actually deal with the SQL so we're like two people on opposite sides of the river! I will raise this with those who do deal with it. Could you explain a little more about this issue?

Comment: Scalar functions, especially when used in a select list, usually are very poor from a performance perspective. There are usually better set based approaches that can make these a lot faster. If the performance is acceptable then it may well not be worth the effort. Sadly this would be like you explaining ruby to me. I will get it but it takes a LOT of explanation to understand the whole picture. :)

Comment: @Sean Lange Me explaining ruby to you would be like a blind man telling another blind man what he can see lol. Anyway thanks for the info. Will pass it on to the sql people.